# How to alert PHP value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
    <?php
    $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>" ?>
</script>

<?php echo 'php_'.$abc; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = "<?php echo $abc; ?>";
</script>

<?php
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert(test)';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

How to alert test variable, which contains PHP value?
I would like to get the PHP value in javascript, for further execution in my project.

Comment: instead of echo just use alert(test) inside script tags

Comment: `echo 'alert("test")';`

Comment: @krishna this is php file.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger test is a variable.

Comment: You have errors in your code.

Comment: try and run it lol, it @RahilWazir is right

Comment: Yes i did. It gives me no error. it returns string successfully, bt not variable.

Comment: The problem is you're closing the script tag and then opening another. If you want to access the variable in the first don't close and open a new script tag, put them both in the same one.

Comment: I tried that too.. no change.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
<?php
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("'.$test.'"); </script>';
?>
```

this is updated code for you using javascript and PHP

```
<?php 
   $user = "rebel";

   echo '<script> var name = "'.$user.'";
   alert(name);</script>';
?>
```

This is the third code for you if this does not work then you have other problem

```
<?php 
    $abc= "Hello";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test="<?php echo $abc; ?>";
</script>

<?php
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert(test)';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: @Rebel do you get alert? if yes then check for your variable

Comment: i have used, var test="<?php echo $abc; ?>";

Comment: @Rebel check my answer again it work for me so i give you demo code just run in your php code and try to solve your problem...i think it will sure work for you

Comment: @rebel If you've copied that code ***exactly*** as it is and are getting a blank alert box then something other than your code is wrong.

Comment: @Prafulla sir, i get " alert(name); " as an output

Comment: @Rebel now I again edit my answer if this not work for you then you have some other problem plz check for that

Comment: Thanks for your effort sir, but no alert box is coming now.

Answer (score 1):

why are you assigning the variable to a javascript variable and then echoing that? sounds like extra work to me...

```
echo 'alert("' . $abc . '");';
```

Comment: i need to use that varaible, thats why.

Comment: That won't work. You still need the double quotes around the variable like: `echo 'alert("' . $abc . '");';`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not so clear, i think you want something like this:

```
<?php
    $test = "hi there!";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("'.$test.'")';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Test is javascript variable, not php variable sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test="<?php echo $abc; ?>"
    <script language="javascript">alert(test); </script>
```

Comment: i like to alert javascript variable

Comment: then alert(test); that's it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alert the value of $abc, you need to escape the slash in the following line with a backslash, like this.

```
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)<\/script>" ?>
```

You also need to remove this line (or escape the < and the > in $abc). If you don't, the script tags will mess up the rendered html code.

```
<?php echo  'php_'.$abc; ?>
```

Comment: No, you don't need to do that.

Comment: @Styphon If you want to alert the string "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>", you do need to escape the slash (because of the script tag)... Please have a look here: https://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2007/04/25/using-script-in-a-javascript-literal/